# extract blocks using the Mean Square Error matlab

Tags: matlab

The `Mean Square Error(MSE)`, is a method used to define the difference in between two blocks, and can be calculated as follow: `a` and `b` two blocks equal size

```
MSE = sqrt(sum(sum((a-b).^2)))/size(a or b)
```

If the `MSE` is less than a given threshold, than the two blocks are not different.

Given a matrix `A`, already reshaped to be contain blocks all in the same raw,
the purpose is to extract all blocks where the `MSE` is less than a given threshold (based on the first block), then return the mean of those blocks. again, extract the second group of blocks which the `MSE` is less than the given threshold where the blocks that already assigned to be a part of other group of blocks must not be extracted again. Better than that, it must be deleted to reduce the search time. and so on till all blocks of the matrix `A` are assigned to be part of a group. And here is an example :

Given matrix `A` where the size of `A` is 2 by 14:

```
A= [1 1  2 2  9 9  4 4  6 6  5 5  3 3 
    1 1  2 2  9 9  4 4  6 6  5 5  3 3];
```

PS: its not necessary the blocks contain the same numbers, it is just to make the example clear.

blocks size is : 2 by 2

the threshold is 2

now we extract all blocks where the `MSE` is less than the threshold starting from the first block in the matrix `A`. so the blocks are:

```
1 1  2 2  3 3
1 1  2 2  3 3
```

the mean of those blocks is

```
  Result= [ 2 2
            2 2];
```

again. we extract all blocks where the `MSE` is less than the threshold, but we need to avoid the blocks that already extracted, so the second group of blocks is :

```
9 9
9 9
```

the mean of this block is it self, so:

```
Result= [2 2  9 9
         2 2  9 9];
```

again. we extract all blocks where the `MSE` is less than the threshold, but we need to avoid the blocks that already extracted, so the third group of blocks is :

```
    4 4  6 6  5 5  
    4 4  6 6  5 5
```

the block

```
3 3 
3 3
```

is not a part of this group even if the `MSE` is less then the threshold because  is already extracted to be part of the first group.

the mean of those blocks is:

```
5 5
5 5
```

therefore the result should be:

```
Result= [2 2  9 9 5 5
         2 2  9 9 5 5];
```

there are any fast way to apply that ?

Comment: What's the datasize for your actual A? What's the blocksize for your actual case?

Comment: in the example, the datasize is 2 by 14, and the blocksize in 2 by 2

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
A = [1 1  2 2  9 9  4 4  6 6  5 5  3 3 
     1 1  2 2  9 9  4 4  6 6  5 5  3 3];

blockLen = 2;
MSEthresh = 1;
nBlocks = size(A,2) / blockLen;
meanBlocks = [];
bSelectRefBlock = true;

while(~isempty(A))
    if(bSelectRefBlock)
        %// Select new reference block
        refBlock = A(:, 1:blockLen);
        bSelectRefBlock = false;
        A = A(:, blockLen+1:end);
        iBlock = 1;
        selectedBlocks = refBlock;
    else
        if(iBlock > size(A,2))
            %// End of A reached. Compute mean of selected blocks
            blockCols = reshape(selectedBlocks, [numel(refBlock) numel(selectedBlocks)/numel(refBlock)]);
            meanBlockCols = mean(blockCols, 2);
            meanBlocks(:, end+1:end+blockLen) = reshape(meanBlockCols, [size(refBlock, 1) blockLen]);
            bSelectRefBlock = true;
        else
            %// Test next block with MSE and select if below threshold
            MSE = sqrt(sum(sum((A(:, iBlock:(iBlock+blockLen-1)) - refBlock).^2))) / numel(refBlock);
            if(MSE <= MSEthresh)
                selectedBlocks(:, end+1:end+blockLen) = A(:, iBlock:(iBlock+blockLen-1));
                A(:, iBlock:(iBlock+blockLen-1)) = [];
            else
                iBlock = iBlock + blockLen;
            end
        end
    end
end
%// Compute mean of selected blocks for last group
blockCols = reshape(selectedBlocks, [numel(refBlock) numel(selectedBlocks)/numel(refBlock)]);
meanBlockCols = mean(blockCols, 2);
meanBlocks(:, end+1:end+blockLen) = reshape(meanBlockCols, [size(refBlock, 1) blockLen]);
```

Comment: thank you, but this method is very slow, there are any faster way to do that ?

Comment: Of course there are faster ways! You will notice that the method I wrote moves the blocks between the original array `A` and `selectedBlocks`. While this is illustrative from an algorithmic point of view, and is simple to code (which are the reasons I wrote it this way), it is quite inefficient, as it constantly changes the arrays in memory. A much more efficient way would be to implement the logic of the method using indices over these arrays, rather than changing the arrays themselves. Why don't you give it a shot and see if you can make it go faster?

Comment: Here's a further suggestion: I would work with two index arrays. The first holds the indices of all the remaining available blocks in `A`, and over this `iBlock` iterates instead of `A` in the main `while` loop. The second is a logical array holding the currently selected blocks (instead of `selectedBlocks`), to which a block is added if it passes the MSE threshold, and which is used to computed the mean once the array has been traversed for a certain reference block.

Comment: By the way, just out of interest, what is the size of your data, and what runtimes are you getting?

Comment: the size of data is soo huge, and it's may be more then a matrix of size 5 by 1749600.
to avoid using cell array. when we calculate the MSE of the selected block and we find it less than the threshold, we directly calculate the mean between those two block by calculating the sum over two ,  the third block, if its MSE with the previous block is high then the threshold, we put it in new class, other ways we calculate the means, and that by calculation the sum of those block over 3, and so on. is it much easier ?

Comment: Indeed, that is another good idea - to sum the elements as you go and then get the mean by dividing by the number of elements in the end.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this really isn't the right site for this kind of request. I gave you an answer to the question you asked, despite the fact that you didn't show any effort to solve it yourself. Now you're asking for optimized code, instead of trying to optimize it yourself, and when a method has already been suggested, which only requires subtle changes to the available implementation. This really is the time to do your work yourself.

Comment: You should edit your post with the code you are using, and explain what your current problem is and what you have tried already. Give relevant details and show that you've put in some effort! For a question about running times, it's important to say what size of data are you working with, and what are your current run times. And show that you've done the research: a good place to start would be [relevant MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/accelerating-matlab-algorithms-and-applications.html) (and links therein).